# How to delete a double feature in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, features

I am working with QGis, and I have a layer that has some double features. I want to delete one of them, but not both of them.
How can I do that easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both features share the same geometries, you can use the **Delete duplicate geometries** tool from the *Processing Toolbox*:

[image: Delete duplicate geometries]

Another method is to use the **Dissolve** tool (*Vector* > *Geoprocessing Tools* > *Dissolve*). However, you would need to make sure that each feature has a **unique** attribute. If any features share the same attribute (which your "double features" should) then they would combine with the other feature of the same attribute to create a single feature.

[image: Dissolve]

---

**EDIT**:

To answer the comment, select all attributes from the new layer created with either of the tool mentioned above and click the **Copy** icon (make sure you're in editing mode). Then edit your original layer and click the **Paste** icon then save:

[image: Editing]

Comment: Thank you Joseph. 

I have another question. How can I save in the same Layer. Is there any way?

Comment: Most welcome Po Po. I would suggest saving the output as a file and use that instead of the original layer. The layer should be exactly the same except for the duplicates. If you really wanted to then you can copy/paste the features from the new layer into the original layer. I will edit my post to highlight this.

Comment: @PoPo - No worries :)